# How to get rid of the json attributes "variant", "annotations", from the response

Tags: annotations, jersey, dropwizard, variant

I have started using the dropwizard to develop a REST server. The Issue as long resource-method return an EntityType (say Enrolment), the out put is as expected but I have decided to send custom status codes using the below code
`Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
                .entity(Entity.json(new enrolment, AdapterResponseStatus.FAILURE)))
                .build();`

Everything is fine but the out put now contains a few more extra extra attributes as shown below.

`{
        "entity":
        {
            "id": 1267,
            "courseId": "5798890",
            "userName": "user@abc.com",
            "tenantId": "tenant1",
            "status": "approved",
            "link": "/enrollments/null"
        },
        "variant":
        {
            "language": null,
            "mediaType":
            {
                "type": "application",
                "subtype": "json",
                "parameters":
                {
                },
                "wildcardType": false,
                "wildcardSubtype": false
            },
            "encoding": null,
            "languageString": null
        },
        "annotations":
        [
        ],
        "mediaType":
        {
            "type": "application",
            "subtype": "json",
            "parameters":
            {
            },
            "wildcardType": false,
            "wildcardSubtype": false
        },
        "language": null,
        "encoding": null
    }`

I was expecting "entity" property alone but was getting other attributes. Is there any to get rid of them as no one is going to consuming them?

Those tags appear even if I replace my entity object (enrolment) with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the signature of the `ResponseBuilder`'s `entity` method, it takes the object directly; unlike Jersey client which requires a special `Entity` object that coincidentally has `annotations` and `variants` fields within.

Change your code to this:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
                .entity(new Enrolment())
                .build();
```

Comment: Hi Natan,

Thanks for the response. That worked for me. Rather than trying to return a JSON object, from the resource methods, I would have to return to EntityObject itself.